# Getting all results from 3 tables without repetition

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I have 3 tables: `sports`, `venues` and `instructors`, they all have an `id` and a `name`. Instead of having 3 separate `SELECT * FROM table` I want to fetch the results with a single query so that the result is something like:

```
+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
| sport_id | sport_name | venue_id | venue_name | instructor_id | instructor_name |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
|        1 | Sport1     |        1 | Venue1     |             1 | Instructor1     |
|        2 | Sport2     |        2 | Venue2     |             2 | Instructor2     |
|        3 | Sport3     |          |            |             3 | Instructor3     |
|        4 | Sport4     |          |            |               |                 |
+----------+------------+----------+------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM sports, venues, instructors
```

However there are at ton of repetitions.

**EDIT:** The 3 tables are not related to each other in any way.

Comment: how these three tables relate to each other? show your create table code of all the above tables.

Comment: `The 3 tables are not related to each other in any way.` as you said then how can you relate these tables to each other in order to obtain the above output?

Comment: I have a 4th table which relates the 3. I just need to get **all** of the data from the tables with a single query without it being related in any way.

Comment: if you have a 4th assignment table, then these tables relate to each other....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I see limited use for getting all the values in one query, you could alway use `UNION ALL` to get all the values;

```
SELECT sport_id id,      sport_name name,      'sport' type      FROM sports
UNION ALL 
SELECT venue_id id,      venue_name name,      'venue' type      FROM venues
UNION ALL 
SELECT instructor_id id, instructor_name name, 'instructor' type FROM instructors
```

This will give output in the format;

```
id    name           type
-------------------------------
1     sport1         sport
2     sport2         sport
3     sport3         sport
4     sport4         sport

1     venue1         venue
2     venue2         venue

1     instructor1    instructor
2     instructor2    instructor
3     instructor3    instructor
```